# Strange anchors added to end of urls

Tags: url

My EE build is appending these strange anchors to the end of all pages. It's not actually causing any problems, but want to send to the client and want to understand why.

http://s168070.gridserver.com/community/#.UZ5IgqvFQrU

Any tips!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have ShareThis on those pages? It appends silly looking hashes like that to the URLS

Comment: I have add this... could it be the thing doing that?

Comment: I would say, yes. Try removing it and see if the fragments disappear.

Comment: This was the first site in a while I grabbed new addthis code and it was the culprit. Thanks very much @foamcow.

Comment: You have got to be kidding me, why would they think that is okay?  Thanks for the answer this was the cause and solution to my issue as well.